# QGIS select feature, "add to current selection" feature

Tags: qgis, features, select

I am trying to perform a feature selection on qgis similar to "add to current selection"  interactive selection method in Arcgis Desktop, is that possible?

An example: I perform a spatial query and select a set of features, afterwards I need to manually add a couple of features to this set,  if I use the feature selection button I lose my first selection, and start a new one.

Any way of adding features to a selection? Many thanks everyone in advance,

Comment: You can hold the Control key when clicking the desired features. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks Jake,that won't work in this case (I've already tried), as I am doing a spatial selection first and am trying to add features to my selection afterwards

Answer (score 10):

You can do it in several different ways. Assuming you already have a selection, you can add new feature to your selection by:

- Select them interactivelly with any of the selections tool(Rectangle,
  Polygon, freehand), **pressing "Ctrl" or "cmd"** (Like jake already
  said). Take notice that if you select a already selected feature, it
  will be unselected;

[image]

- If you wish to add features by a new spatial query, in the spatial
  query plugin you can use "**add to current selection**" in the "And use
  result to" option;

[image]

- You can also use the "Select Feature by using an Expression" tool, create a desired expression and use the **"add to selection"** option;

[image]

Note 1: In all methods, the active layer must be the one you need to add or remove features from selection;

Note 2: You can use the same methods to remove a few features from the current selection.

Hope it helps!

Comment: "Add to current layer" should probably be "Add to current selection" :)

Comment: thanks a lot, but I knew those methods. The point is selecting features by one of these functions (spatial, expression), keeping the selection, maybe look up statistics of the selected features, and, later, perform a new selection (point, rectangle tipically, but could be spatial or expression). I want this new selection to add up to the first one, instead of "replacing" it.

Comment: If you follow my instructions, all methods add features to the current selection. I have updated the answer to highlight the important parts of using the selection tools to get what you need. If this does not work for you, then I don't understand your question.

Comment: Alexandre, I can do many kinds of selections with your methods, and using them I will manage to do this job. But what I intend and can´t is adding a manual selection (or multi-selection via CTRL) to a previous spatial or expression selection. CTRL wouldn't work, and there is no 'add to selection' option. Thanks a lot anyway for your answer, which is really complete and clear.

Comment: @Guillermo, that is strange, I can add features to the selection by holding CTRL (it works as if it is a "add to selection" option). What version of QGIS are you using, and in what platform?

Comment: Alexandre, I am using QGIS 2.0 32b on Windows 7. I managed to do it changing the order, 1st the manual selection and 2nd the spatial one, but that is not possible in some tasks I usually perform

Answer (score 10):

Just in case someone else should come across this question and wonder why the `Ctrl` key modifier doesn't work..

As pointed out in a [related answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217349/34474):

> in 2.18, holding **Shift** adds features, while **Ctrl** removes features

This is works the same way in QGIS 3.0

(Though I think the "add to current selection" is the ultimate solution to the algebra.)

Answer (score 0):

Updating this thread.

For version 3.22, the behavior is:

**CTRL** for subtracting from selected features
**SHIFT** for adding to selected features