# QGIS Feature Selection - Add to Current Selection

Tags: qgis, features, select

I have recently started working in QGIS. I need to select multiple features loaded in map canvas one by one. To select a feature in addition to the selected features in the map canvas, I need to hold the 'CTRL' key. Is there settings options available in QGIS so that I can configure the 'Add to current selection' without holding the 'CTRL' key?

Comment: Duplicate of [this older post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75463/qgis-select-feature-add-to-current-selection-feature), which has some filtering alternatives to the control key but no answer like the "add to current selection" feature.

Comment: I have already seen that post @NateWanner. I need to know whether we can modify the selection settings such that the newly selected feature will add to the current selection (without holding the CTRL key)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a setting to keep adding features to a selection without holding a modifier key.

That said, in 2.18, holding Shift adds features, while Ctrl removes features for me.